# How to add custom field in Sidebar under Feature Image column?

Tags: wordpress

I am using WebDevStudios/CMB2 to create custom fields for WordPress posts, that is working fine. My question is how can I add field in sidebar in area where Featured Image located.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `add_meta_box()` for solving your problem. This function should be called from `add_meta_boxes` action. For more information please refer to http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box.

Comment: my question for this utility to manage custom fields https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2